# I want to create a custom event which can trigger from any component and get listened to any component within my angular 7 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I want to create a custom event which can trigger from any component and get listened to any component within my angular 7 app

Suppose I have 1 component in which I have a button on click on which I want to trigger my custom event with some data. Next, there will be another component which will constantly listening for that event when it triggers it will execute some code and update the ui accordingly.

How should I implement it?

Comment: Create a shared service, and use Observables.

Comment: Can you share a working demo please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, well, well, what you're looking for is a Shared Service. This shared service will have a `BehaviorSubject` that will act as a source for the data. Through this, you will be able to push new data streams. And then you will expose this `BehaviorSubject` `asObservable`.

You will then `subscribe` to this `Observable` from all the components where you want to listen for data changes and then react accordingly.

This is what this is going to look like in code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  data$: Observable<any> = this.data.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setData(newData) {
    this.data.next(newData);
  }

}
```

You can now inject the `SharedService` in any controller you want and call `setData` from the component that you want to push new data from(see the `AppComponent` from the Sample StackBlitz for more details). And then you'll also be injecting the `SharedService` in other components and in there, you'll `subscribe` to `data$` in their `ngOnInit`(see the `HelloComponent` from the Sample StackBlitz for details)

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-share-data-using-shared-service?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: `export class EventsService {

     private expandNavSubject = new BehaviorSubject < any > (null);

     trigExpandNav() {
     this.expandNavSubject.next(1);
     }

     get expandNav$() {
     this.expandNavSubject.asObservable();
     }

     constructor() {}
     }` 

This is my service right now

Comment: Actually I'm having trouble in listening the event. The subscriber is under ngOnit and it is being triggered automatically when the component is initialising and after that when I am triggering the event it is not listening.

Comment: Did you have a look at the sample stackblitz?

Comment: Yes I did and I have done exactly the same still the issue persist

Comment: @ShreyanshMehta In your `header.component.ts`, you've created a separate `providers` entry for your service. You need to remove that line, otherwise the 2 components are not sharing the same instance of the service

Comment: Yeap. Doing `providers: [EventsService]` in the HeaderComponent's `@Component` decorator metadata will create a new instance of the EventsService. Just remove it from there so that all your components get the `EventsService` injected from the root injector.